# Android about set Image on the List

Tags: android-listview, android-arrayadapter

I have a little trouble about android.
I have data in my DataBase(phpadmin) and the data type is varchar(20).
The content of data is "R.drawable.Imagename".
Now how should I do to get the data from database?
And if I get the data,how should I do put the data into Array(the type of array is integer).
Because I want to set Image on the List.
Graph:
(DataBase)────>(Get Data)────>(put into List)
Tks for ur help.
P.s. Sorry my English is not well.Except u can understand what I want to ask.

Answer (score 0):

Since you mentioned "phpadmin" ([phpmyadmin](http://www.phpmyadmin.net/)?), I'm assuming you're using a MySQL database on a server somewhere instead of a local [SQLite](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#db) database on the android device itself (which I recommend).

As far as I know, MySQL support in the Android SDK is limited or even non-existent, so you would have to create a small PHP/Perl/... wrapper around your MySQL database and have it return the data as JSON or XML to be consumed by your android application.

As for loading the resources, I would suggest you store the drawable identifier as `image_name` as opposed to `R.drawable.image_name`. That way, you can just do the following to get the ID of the needed resource and store it in your Array of integers:

```
int resource_id = getResources().getIdentifier("image_name", "drawable", getPackageName());
```

After that, it's just a matter of using an adapter to load the images specified by the identifiers into a List.

Let me know if I need to clear anything up.

Comment: Thank you very much!!!!I test ur method,and I success put Image into List.u are my God,haha Tks you again.

Comment: Glad to help, Wu. Would you mind marking my post as the answer so others know that this is solved?